# Animating fade in/out of TextView whilst changing text

Tags: android, animation

Basically I want to use an `AlphaAnimation` to fade a `TextView` out, then change the text of that `TextView`, and then finally fade it back in again using another `AlphaAnimation`. But I don't know how to perform this sequentially. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: do u want to fadeout the textview with onclick/ontouch? if yes let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a clean solution, it's called [TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html). Does what I want with less fuss.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this,

place two textviews one above the other and set different text for the two textviews and with onclick you can fadeout and fadein the two views(Remember two views shd have the same orientation)

Check this code.

```
  AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ) ; 
   fadeIn.setDuration(1200);
   fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);

      AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation( 1.0f , 0.0f ) ; 
     fadeOut.setDuration(1200);
    fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);

     mswtview4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
    mswtview4.startAnimation(fadeOut);
    mswtview4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
  });

    mswtview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mswtview2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        mswtview4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
});
```